# C# deskew colored image with Accord framework

Tags: c#, bitmap, skew, accord.net

I am using the accord framework to deskew an image that I loaded into a bitmap. Now the problem I keep having is that I want to deskew an image that contains color but every time I try to deskew it, it keeps asking for a greyscaled image. Now using graphics I am able to convert it to a 8bpp greyscaled pixelformat so I'm able to deskew it but I don't need the greyscaled corrected image, I need the colored one.

Is there any possible way to do this with the accord framework?

This is the code i'm currently using.

```
    public Bitmap DeskewImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {
       DocumentSkewChecker sc = new DocumentSkewChecker();
       Bitmap workmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
       Bitmap workmap1 = new Bitmap(bmp);
       Bitmap tempWorkmap = new Bitmap(workmap.Width, workmap.Height);
       using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempWorkmap)) 
            g.DrawImage(workmap, 0, 0);
       Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
       workmap = filter.Apply(tempWorkmap);
       double angle = sc.GetSkewAngle(workmap);
       RotateBilinear rf = new RotateBilinear(-angle);
       rf.FillColor = Color.White;
       workmap1 = rf.Apply(workmap);
       return workmap1;
    }
```